# form validation using java script

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Following form validates using JavaScript,but its not working. It still takes action,instead of showing error.I cant figure out what is wrong with code. It seems fine. Can anyone show me my mistakes?

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>

function formValidator(){

    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var alpha = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

    if(!alpha.test.(name.value)){
        alert('Please provide a valid name');
        name.focus;
        return false;

    }

    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
    alert('Please provide a valid email address');
    email.focus;
    return false;
 }
}
</script>

<div id="contact_form">
                     <p>Stay Connected.</p>
                            </div>
  <form name="contact" method="post" action="sendmail.php" onsubmit='return formValidator();'>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name" id="name_label">Your name *</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="50" value="" class="text-input" required  />


      <label for="email" id="email_label">Your email address *</label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />



        <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button btn btn-primary btn-info" id="submit_btn" value="Send" onclick='Javascript:formValidator();'/>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

 I dont want to use only html5 validation.
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: `name.focus;` -> `name.focus();` and `email.focus` -> `email.focus();`

Comment: that is not the problem anyway

Comment: @user1990577 thanks for point it out.

Comment: @rightfold form takes action instead of showing error.but now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the error in console

```
SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
[Break On This Error]   

if(!alpha.test.(name.value)){
```

so use

```
if (!filter.test(name.value))  instead of if(!alpha.test.(name.value)){
```

remove `.`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the if statements are never true, so false is never returned.

Answer (score 0):

replace `if (!filter.test.(name.value)) {`
  to

```
  if (!filter.test(name.value)) {
```